# XCB Set Window On Top Not Working

Tags: xcb

I am trying to set a managed window to be always on top. However this code is not working:

My code is js-ctypes, but its a XCB API question:

```
var rez_focus = xcb_get_input_focus_reply(c, xcb_get_input_focus(c), null);

var change_list = xcb_atom_t.array()([cachedXCBAtom('_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE')]);
var req_change = xcb_change_property(c, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, rez_focus.focus, cachedXCBAtom('_NET_WM_STATE'), XCB_ATOM_ATOM, 32, change_list.length, change_list);

xcb_flush(c);
```

I tested that I have the right window, by getting the window title. However This code above is not making the window be always on top. Can you please advise.

I had got the feeling maybe the window I got was not the "owner window", meaning that its not responsible for being always on top, so I did query tree and tried with each window on top (except root), however none worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should state what window manager you are testing this with and verify via `_NET_SUPPORTED` on the root window that the window manager supports this atom.

Secondly, you are violating the specification. Setting the atom directly is only honored by the window manager when the window is withdrawn and then mapped. If you want to do this for an already mapped window, you need to use a client message to the root window instead.

See [the documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html):

> The Window Manager SHOULD honor _NET_WM_STATE whenever a withdrawn window requests to be mapped. A Client wishing to change the state of a window MUST send a _NET_WM_STATE client message to the root window (see below). The Window Manager MUST keep this property updated to reflect the current state of the window.

Comment: Thanks Ingo! I'm trying to follow this guide right here - http://libxcb.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1/group__XCB____API_g8f8291858b47fd9c88f07d96720fbd7c.html#g8f8291858b47fd9c88f07d96720fbd7c on how to send event :) I am testing this in OpenSuse which I think is KDE WM.

Comment: Hi @ingo I tried this but its not working - I'm sending a message now, its weird, may you please take a look - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3165899d91d678e3ea7648e40f6d1acd

Comment: From looking at it it seems fine. Have you checked for an error response?

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I didn't check for error response I'll do that and report back :)

Comment: Oooo Ingo I figured it out. I was getting the current focused window with `xcb_get_input_focus`. So I would send the message with this window id. But when I got the window title of this window it was a blank string. So i did query parents with `xcb_query_tree` until I found a window with a title that wasn't blank. I sent the set on top to that window (with title) and it set on top. Is there anyway to know if setting that window on top is what I expect? I did a `xcb_send_event_checked` after sending to that window with blank title, and no error on check, it was null.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's actually an old problem. :-) My suggestion is that you look at the `xwininfo` source code. They have a function that takes care of this (I forget the actual algorithm they use). Given that it's a time-proven tool their solution should be good enough.

Comment: Thank you sir I'll take a look right away! :) Your references have helped me so much, you are a wealth of knowledge!

Comment: Hi there Ingo, I was checking out `xwininfo` here - https://opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-13/xwininfo/xwininfo-X11R7.1-1.0.2/xwininfo.c - and I was a bit confused which part was picking out the proper window to do "set top" on. I see in a comment here `find our window manager frame, if any`, is what they call `window manager frame` the window of interest for setting on top?

Comment: @Noitidart You're looking for something like [this](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/xdo.c#L1173), although I think checking for `WM_CLASS` is dangerous. `_NET_WM_STATE` would be better and is used by most other tools (but they search in the opposite way, from top down). However, do you really need the window with input focus? You might want the active window instead. This requires EWMH support, but is much easier to find. Just query `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` from the root window.

Comment: Just for reference, the code you were looking for is `Select_Window` from [here](http://opensource.apple.com//source/X11apps/X11apps-30/xwininfo/xwininfo-1.0.4/dsimple.c) which then uses `Find_Client` from [here](http://opensource.apple.com//source/X11apps/X11apps-30/xwininfo/xwininfo-1.0.4/clientwin.c). As I said, though, these look the other way around.

Comment: Thanks much @Ingo! Yes I need the focused :( But that is a super cool method that can come in handy thanks!

Comment: @Noitidart Out of curiosity, what's the usecase for this where the active window won't be the focused window? :-)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think you're right, the active window is always focused. My personal use case was I have overide redirect window, which spawns a "file browse dialog". Now this thing pops up in back. And I'm trying to bring it forward. It has the focus, for sure as i can hit enter and it saves.

Comment: It will also be the active window simply because your override redirect window can't be it since it's not managed. I would suggest you go with `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` and only put in the additional effort if it doesn't work out for some reason. :-)

Comment: Ohh you are right!!! That has to be the case! Super smart!  Shoot I'll try this thank you sir!